# Finding potential for vector field and compute line integral using Maple

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maple

I am given a question to be solved on Maple which gives me a vector field $$\vec{F}(x, y, z)=\left \langle \frac{y}{1+x^2y^2}, \frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}+\frac{z}{\sqrt(1-y^2z^2)}, \frac{y}{\sqrt(1-y^2z^2)}+\frac{1}{z}\right \rangle$$ and I am asked to find a potential f(x, y, z) for the vector field, and compute $$ \int_{C} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$ where C is the arc parametrized by 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}x=t^3+t+1 \\ y=3t^2+1 \\ z=t^4-t^3-3t^2+3t+\frac{1}{5} \end{matrix}\right.$$
with $$0\leq t\leq 1$$

I have already calculated the potential using

```
 potential(f, [x,y,z], 'F')
```

I do not know how to proceed after finding the potential (ie. what commands are needed, procedures, etc). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need the endpoints now, that is you need the fundamental theorem of line integrals